# Inno Setup - See how many components are selected

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

Actually, I only need to see if it's `1` or more. Here's how I'm planning to use it:

```
if [Only one component is selected] then
begin
  Result := CustomMessage('[Name of that component]');
  if IsComponentSelected('[Specific Component]') then
  begin
    if IsTaskSelected('[Task]') then
    begin
      Result := CustomMessage('[Name of that task]');
    end
  end
end
if [More than one component is selected] then
begin
  Result := 'Full Feature';// or '{#SetupSetting("AppName")}'
end;
```

I think I know at least one "workaround" way to do this, but I'm wondering if this can be done with more conventional Inno ways (and cleaner code).

**-----Edit-----**

Final function using Martins answer:

```
function UninstallName(Value: string): string;
begin
  if GetSelectedComponentsCount = 1 then
  begin
    Result := CustomMessage(WizardSelectedComponents(False));
    if IsComponentSelected('bc2') then
    begin      
      if IsTaskSelected('bc2tp2') then
      begin
        Result := CustomMessage('bc2tp2');
      end;
    end;
    if Pos(':',Result) > 1 then
    StringChangeEx(Result, ':', ' -', False)
  end;
  if GetSelectedComponentsCount > 1 then
  begin
    Result := '{#SetupSetting("AppName")}';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Next time, show us your workaround. It's your responsibility, to show, what you have tried already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect the `WizardForm.ComponentsList`:

```pascal
function GetSelectedComponentsCount: Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for I := 0 to WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[I] then
      Result := Result + 1;
  end;
end;
```

---

You can also count number of elements in [`WizardSelectedComponents`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardselectedcomponents):

```pascal
function GetSelectedComponentsCount: Integer;
var
  S: TStringList;
begin
  S := TStringList.Create();
  S.CommaText := WizardSelectedComponents(False);
  Result := S.Count;
  S.Free;
end;
```

(Counting commas would be more efficient and slightly less code, but cryptic to understand.)

Comment: `GetSelectedComponentsCount` proved very useful for me. Thank you. My "workaround" was similar to your second answer (used WizardSelectedComponents), but by far not as compact.